# Separating ManyToManyFields in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

Following my question at [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561039/rendering-a-manytomany-field) I'd like to separate the features in the template using categories such as Interior, Exterior, Mechanical etc.

I'm trying out the code below, but apparently it's not giving me what I want.

```
{% for feature in vehicle.features.all %}
    {% ifequal vehicle.features.type.type "Interior" %}
    <li>{{ feature }}</li>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
{% for feature in vehicle.features.all %}
    {% ifequal feature.type.type "Interior" %}
        <li>{{ feature }}</li>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

vehicle.features is a `ManyToManyRelatedManager` which can be used to access `Feature` objects, but does not actually carry `Feature`'s relationships.

EDIT: In response to the comment below about doing this on the view, you could easily do:

```
interior_features = vehicle.features.filter(type__type='Interior')
```

and pass interior_features to the context of the template directly.  This would actually make more sense as a method on the model:

```
def get_interior_features(self):
    return self.features.filter(type__type='Interior')
```

The result of this could be filtered further, of course, as needed.

```
options = vehicle.get_interior_features().filter(is_standard=False)
```

or something.

Comment: BTW...just wondering is there a way to do this inside my view befor I render on to the template?

Comment: you're a life-saver...thank you.  I'd up vote again if I could :)

Comment: how do I use the same method for displaying the feature_sets field? I tried the same ay, but for feature_sets and all I get is -'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'features'  The features and feature_sets fields also appear in the CommonVehicle class, but they are skipped entirely in the template

Comment: It's not clear where your `feature_set` manager is coming from.  How is `feature_set` different from `features`?  At any rate, your error message tells you it is a `ManyRelatedManager`.  So was `features`, so treat it the same.

Comment: @jcd I managed to sort out the issue...just a minor typo on my part :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Django's regroup tag: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

Would probably end up looking something like:

```
{% regroup vehicle.features.all by type as vehicle_features %}

{% for feature in vehicle_features %}
  {% ifequal feature "Interior" %}
     <li>{{feature}}</li>
  {% endifequal %}
{% endfor %}
```